# I have two PHP files. In my 1st PHP file I have a variable named "url" (which was taken from another HTML page)

Tags: php

How can I send this variable to my 2nd PHP page? I want to access this variable in 2nd one. Something like this.

PHP file 1:
$url=$_POST['URL'];

PHP file 2:
how can I access $url here?

Comment: Assuming you are clicking a link in one to get to the other: you can add the value to a session variable, if you have started a session, or you can `urlencode()` it and pass it via the query string. Or, you can save it to a database record and read it from the database in the second page. Each of these approaches have their pros and cons, so you may find working through some solid tutorials/books helpful, to get a broader appreciation of how they are different.

Comment: (If one file is included in the other, then that's a different matter, and you'll need to clarify to explain which scenario you mean).